# Writing a unary function chainer, TypeError on codewars but no error on repl.it?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, chaining, declarative-programming

I worked on this problem on code wars for a little while and used repl.it to test it out. It's a simple unary function chainer, but it only works on repl.it, while codewars will give me a TypeError when given this code:

```
function chained(functions) {
  var funcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return function (value){

    var finalValue = funcs.reduce(function(prevVal, currFunc){

        return currFunc(prevVal);

    }, value);

    return finalValue;
  }
}
```

It tells me currFunc is not a function, but using the following test code I get the correct answers while running in repl.it:

```
function f1(x){ return x*2 }
function f2(x){ return x+2 }
function f3(x){ return Math.pow(x,2) }
console.log(chained(f1,f2,f3)(0));
```

Is there a reason why it isn't a function in codewars?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: This:     TypeError: currFunc is not a function
           at Array.reduce
        at doFunc
                at Object.handleError
            at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext

Comment: Are you sure that codewars is running exactly the code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

I had to look up the test on codewars. They give you this boilerplate ...

```
function chained(functions) {
  //FIXME
}
```

Looking at the tests you can see that functions are being passed in an array ...

```
Test.assertEquals( chained([f1,f2,f3])(0), 4 )
Test.assertEquals( chained([f1,f2,f3])(2), 36 )
Test.assertEquals( chained([f3,f2,f1])(2), 12 )
```

---

The mistake you made is ...

```
var funcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

... which would only work if `chained` was called like this ...

```
chained(f1,f2,f3)
```

---

Your code otherwise works and passes all tests on codewars. Here's the complete change ...

```
function chained(functions) {
  var funcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function (value){
    var finalValue = funcsfunctions.reduce(function(prevVal, currFunc){
      return currFunc(prevVal);
    }, value);
    return finalValue;
  }
}
```

---

Lastly, here's my solution ^_^

```
const id = x => x;
const uncurry = f => (x,y) => f (x) (y);
const rcomp = f => g => x => g (f (x));
const chained = fs => fs.reduce(uncurry(rcomp), id);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

While @naomik's solution is the correct answer and should be accepted, I just wanted to share an alternate solution using good old fashioned ES3:

```js
function chained(functions) {
    return function(x) {
        var fs = functions, i = fs.length, y = x;
        while (i > 0) y = fs[--i](y);
        return y;
    };
}
```

This is just to show that you don't really need to use `reduce` to write succinct code in this particular case. Furthermore, using a `while` loop is better for performance than using `reduce`. Finally, this code is also very understandable. You don't need to mentally juggle with reducing `id` and `uncurry(rcomp)` to understand how chaining can be implemented by folding functions.

Answer (score 0):

The same idea just in ES6. Fun is an array of functions.

```
const chained = fun => {
    return input => {
        return fun.reduce((acc, currentFun) => currentFun(acc), input);
    }
};
```

and in a little more difficult to read but beautiful modern JS version:

```
const chained = fun => input => fun.reduce((acc, currentFun) => currentFun(acc), input);
```